# conditional vs subjunctive: "it would mean they (were / would be)"

Tags: modal-verbs, subjunctives

I have a hard time convincing someone that the correct verb to use in the following sentence is the conditional "would be" rather than the subjunctive "were":

> One interviewee  expressed hope that this would happen, as it would mean markets  **were**  better informed and serving disaster risk reduction.

Comment: Either is fine. I personally prefer the use of *were*, if only to avoid the repetition—three *woulds* is quite awkward. (Even without the repetition, I'd probably prefer the subjunctive. But, as I say, both are grammatical.)

Comment: "Were" is not subjunctive, but a modal preterite, a preterite where the meaning has to do with modality rather than past time. Note that there is no such thing as a 'past subjunctive' -- it's an ill-named term.